# Como hago para primero escanear todos los digitos y luego hacer el bucle

Tags: c, funciones, bucle-for, binario

Tengo este codigo para pasar de decimal a binario, en el que pongo primero la cantidad de numeros que quiero pasar a binario, y luego voy introduciendo cada digito. El problema que tengo es que cada vez que pongo un digito para pasar a binario, me lo imprime directamente, y mi duda es como podria hacer para poder poner todos los digitos para pasar a binario, y luego que me imprima seguidos los numeros ya en binario

```
void traductor (int n) {
    if (n) {
        traductor(n / 2);
        printf("%d", n % 2);
    }
}

int main() {
    int casos;
    scanf("%d", &casos);

    for (int i = 0; i < casos; i++) {
        int numero;
        scanf("%i", &numero);
        traductor(numero);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando quieras iterar de alguna manera, ya sea mostrar información, recoger información, etc, emplea bucles `for` y un `array` donde almacenar/mostrar la información.

En tu caso necesitamos un array para primero almacenar todos los valores de los números en formato decimal. Una vez que tengamos todo nuestro array completo de los números de entrada, vamos llamando a la función `traductor` de forma ordenada con cada número para que nos saque todos los números en binario.

El código que buscas sería algo parecido a esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void traductor (int n) {
    if (n) {
        traductor(n / 2);
        printf("%d", n % 2);
    }
}

int main() {

    int casos;
    int i=0;
    printf("Cuantos numeros quieres? ");
    scanf("%d", &casos);
    int numero_en_decimal[casos];

    // Aquí rellenamos el array para todos los números decimales
    for (i = 0; i < casos; i++) {
        printf("Inserta el numero %d en formato decimal: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &numero_en_decimal[i]);
    }

    // Aquí llamamos a traductor() para pasarlos a binario
    for (i=0 ; i<casos ; i++) {
        printf("\nEl numero %d en binario es ", numero_en_decimal[i]);
        traductor(numero_en_decimal[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Espero que te sirva ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias ;)